# Compare two tables to check if table two contains ids based on table 1 condition

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have two tables, `T1` which is the original table and the `T2` which is an exact copy of `T1` until I make changes for it.

At the start both `T1` and `T2` looks as follows:

| ID | Event | Event_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | exam - english | 2022-04-04 |
| 001 | exam - biology | 2021-03-01 |
| 002 | exam - maths | 2022-05-23 |
| 002 | exam - english | 2022-05-29 |
| 003 | exam - chemistry | 2022-04-13 |
| 004 | exam - maths | 2021-09-15 |

I've used the following SQL to alter T2:

```
DELETE FROM T2 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM T2 WHERE EVENT_DATE < '2022-01-01')
```

And I should get something that looks like the following:

| ID | Event | Event_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 002 | exam - maths | 2022-05-23 |
| 002 | exam - english | 2022-05-29 |
| 003 | exam - chemistry | 2022-04-13 |

What I want to do now is just a quality check to make sure that I have deleted all rows where an `ID` has ever had an `event_date < 2022-01-01`.

I've tried to do the following:

```
SELECT T1.ID 
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID 
WHERE T1.EVENT_DATE < '2022-01-01'
```

But I think that's just trying to look for dates `< 2022-01-01` which shouldn't be in `T2` anyway so I don't think that this is the correct way of solving the problem.

Comment: Can you specify which table the `ID` and `EVENT_DATE` columns belong to in the last select statement? As right now that should be giving you an ambiguous column error

Comment: Sorry about that, just edited to add it in @B.Griffin

Comment: In your select select t1.id and t2.id, and rather than an inner join, use a left join.  Your select result should then show the id's existing in t1, but null for t2 column, confirming they were deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Just use Left join instead of Inner join in the query that you have mentioned. It will give you your desired output. Also, you need to add ID column of T2 table so that the NULL values corresponding to ID column of T1 table will help you know which ID was deleted from T2.

```
SELECT T1.ID as T1_ID, T2.ID as T2_ID
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID 
WHERE T1.EVENT_DATE < '2022-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Left join in place of inner join in the query.

```
SELECT T1.ID 
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID 
WHERE T1.EVENT_DATE < '2022-01-01'
```

- It'll return pairs of T1.ID and T2.ID values where T1.EVENT_DATE is before `2022-01-01`, and if there's no match in T2, it will still return T1.ID with a `NULL value` for T2.ID.